# Instagram basic display: Error from android emulator (android 6.0) when trying to login a user

Tags: android, android-emulator, instagram, instagram-api, android-6.0-marshmallow

In my app we are using the instagram basic display.

When working out of a physical device I can use this api with no issue at all

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize
?client_id={app-id}
&redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
&scope=user_profile,user_media
&response_type=code
```

But when trying to use a emulator with Android 6.0 with **no chrome browser** (as the reviewers dictated we should) I get an error with no details (image attached)

Thank you for your help!

[image]